# error to implement trait for function type in Rust

Tags: function, rust, traits

I want to implement the `From` trait for an enum.
It's OK for `usize`, but fail for function type.

Is there any difference between usize and function type?

The code:

```rust
type Foo = fn (usize) -> usize;

enum Value {
    Number(usize),
    Function(Foo),
}

impl From<usize> for Value {
    fn from(n: usize) -> Self {
        Value::Number(n)
    }
}
impl From<Foo> for Value {
    fn from(f: Foo) -> Self {
        Value::Function(f)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let n: usize = 123;
    let vn: Value = n.into(); // OK for usize

    fn testf(n: usize) -> usize { n * n }
    let vf: Value = testf.into(); // fail for Foo
}
```

The error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Value: From<fn(usize) -> usize {testf}>` is not satisfied
  --> t.rs:24:27
   |
24 |     let vf: Value = testf.into(); // fail for Foo
   |                           ^^^^ the trait `From<fn(usize) -> usize {testf}>` is not implemented for `Value`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <Value as From<fn(usize) -> usize>>
             <Value as From<usize>>
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Into<Value>` for `fn(usize) -> usize {testf}`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

The error says that `From<fn(usize) -> usize {testf}>` is needed but only has `From<fn(usize) -> usize>`. I think the problem is `{testf}`, but I do not know why.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Rust, function definitions do not have the `fn` type. They have a distinct, unnameable type that the compiler spells out as `signature {name}`, e.g. `fn(usize) -> usize {testf}`.

This type can be **coerced**, i.e. converted, to the corresponding `fn` type (`fn(usize) -> usize`), and usually it does so automatically, but when working with generics it does not.

You can force the compiler to coerce with `as`:

```rust
fn testf(n: usize) -> usize { n * n }
let vf: Value = (testf as fn(usize) -> usize).into();
```

Or by specifying the type explicitly:

```rust
fn testf(n: usize) -> usize { n * n }
let testf_fn: fn(usize) -> usize = testf;
let vf: Value = testf_fn.into();
```